# Python-3x Unicode Print vs Write

Tags: python, unicode

I created the following program to try to work through what I believe to be a unicode issue:

```
s = '7/02/16;07:30:00;São Paulo-8;Reachability: 18.5%'
s_type = type(s)
print ("variable s contains: ",s)
print ("variable s type is: ", s_type)
text_file = open("test_file.txt", "w")
text_file.write(s)
text_file.close()
```

The print statements provide the following output when the program is run:

```
variable s contains:  7/02/16;07:30:00;São Paulo-8;Reachability: 18.5%
variable s type is:  <class 'str'>
```

When it comes time to write to the file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tglund/Projects/Python/thousandeyes/unicode.py", line 6, in <module>
     text_file.write(s)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe3' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have read the unicode documentation from beginning to end at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

but have not successfully cracked the code.

I can copy the string assigned to the variable `s` and paste it into a file, save the file, then 'more' the file. I am on a Mac, and the string shows on my screen correctly.  The Python print statement shows the string correctly.

My goal of all this is to create a csv text file where the delimiter is ";".  The issue appears to be the accented second character in the location field.  The string for `s` contains the following fields:  Date, Location, Message

Any assistance in how to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error can be reproduced, even on systems that have different defaults, with something like:

```
text_file = open("test_file.txt", "w", encoding='ascii')
text_file.write('\xe3')
```

The issue is that your default text encoding is ascii.  Or at least that's what Python is understanding it to be.  See "encoding" under [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), and [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding).

The easiest way to fix this is to tell Python to open your file with a compatible encoding.  For example UTF-8 (because your character is unicode encoded):

```
text_file = open("test_file.txt", "w")
# Becomes
text_file = open("test_file.txt", "w", encoding='utf_8')
```

And you should be done.